# using delegate as eventhandler parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates

having a function parameter of type delegate.
the function adds an eventhandler and expects the method as parameter.
how to achieve this?

example:

```
private void myFunction( Delegate del )
{
...
var b = new Button();
b.Click += new EventHandler( <method delegate refers to should be used> );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the type of `del` to `EventHandler` then you can just use the following:

```
b.Click += del;
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, no that doesn't make sense - because it could be a delegate of *any* type.

What would you want to happen if the delegate passed in took 15 parameters? How would it be called?

If you could give more information about what you're trying to achieve - and why you're trying to use just `Delegate` instead of some specific delegate type - that would help.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to myFunction should be an `Action<object, EventArgs>`

```
private void myFunction(Action<object, EventArgs> del)
{
  var b = new Button();
  b.Click += new EventHandler(del);
}
```

Or just an `EventHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use such code:

```
    ...............
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }        

    private void MyFunc(EventHandler Meth)
    {
        button1.Click += Meth;
    }

    private void TestCall()
    {
        MyFunc(btn_Click);
    }
    ............
```